# Portable Version of Adobe Software

Tags: adobe

Are portable version of adobe software legal? because when i tried to browse their official site they didn't mention about portable version of their products instead a trial version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO,** they are not legal, at-least not always.

**Adobe Reader** (not Acrobat) is **Freeware**.

*define: freeware,*

> Freeware (portmanteau of "free" and "software") is software that is
>   available for use at no monetary cost, but with **one or more restricted
>   usage rights such as source code being withheld or redistribution**
>   prohibited.[1](http://brackets.io/)[3] Freeware is in contrast to commercial software,
>   which is typically sold for profit, but might be distributed at no
>   cost for a business or commercial purpose in the aim to expand the
>   marketshare of a "premium" product.

And also if you search deeper at **[licenses-terms/pdf/Reader_11_0_en](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/legal/licenses-terms/pdf/Reader_11_0_en.pdf)**,
under sections

```
3.3 Distribution. This license does not grant you the right to sublicense or distribute the Software. For 
information about obtaining the right to distribute the Software on tangible media or through an 
internal network or with your product or service please refer 
to http://www.adobe.com/go/acrobat_distribute for information about Adobe Reader; 
or http://www.adobe.com/go/licensing for information about the Adobe Runtimes.
```

**Even though making a software Portable involves less or no modification to the source code, it is a form of redistribution especially when you make it available to the public.** This is clearly restricted in the documents.

Other Adobe software have similar **Terms of Use.**

One exception is **[Brackets](http://brackets.io/)** which is maintained by Adobe along with a community of other developers. Brackets is **Open Source** (very different from Freeware).

This answer was specific to Adobe software and Adobe Reader. Other companies may have more lenient rules.

Comment: It's not at all true that Brackets "is no longer in development by Adobe" - there's a whole team of engineers working on it full-time. Do you mind if I edit your answer above to correct that?

Comment: Yeah true but are they only adobe engineers? Adobe started the project, and the GitHub community contributes to it.
You may edit the answer as long a it's correct. :-)

Comment: It's certainly not _only_ Adobe engineers, but it's not accurate to  say Adobe isn't involved anymore because they are still the most active contributors to the project. I've submitted an edit to change it to "maintained by Adobe along with a community of other developers" - hope that sounds good.